# How to configure a CSV as datasource in icCube

Tags: csv, iccube

Environment: I am using icCube version 5.2 with Java 8 on Windows.

I tried to configure a folder containing CSV files as datasource in icCube. Here are the steps I followed:

1. I opened the Builder then the Schema Manager (web page), then under the group Default, I created a new schema myschema
2. Under myschema, I chose Data Integration, then tried to configure a new data source for CSV files. I followed the wizard by specifying the complete path of my CSV folder.
3. After, I saved and selected my new data source. But I cannot see anything under "Selected Tables" which should have the list of CSV files in my folder in there.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to manually add "tables" (i.e., files) using the top level '+' icon. Two possibilities then:

1) a table defined by a single file

2) a table defined by several files (use the regular expression of the "File Filter" to select the files)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Very usefull indeed.